# Access class methods from an instance in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

Given the following class,

```
@interface MyBaseClass : NSObject

-(void)printName
+(NSString*)printableName

@end
```

how can I call the class method `+printableName` from within the instance method `-printName` without explicitly referring to `MyBaseClass`? `[[self class] printableName]` doesn't compile.

The idea is that subclasses will override `+printableName` so `-printName` should polymorphically invoke the appropriate `+printableName` for its class.

Comment: What is the compiler error you are seeing?

Comment: `Cannot resolve 'printableName' in NSObject`

Answer (score 1):

Declare MyBaseClass as

```
@interface MyBaseClass : NSObject
```

and your [[self class] name] should compile.

This compiles for me:

```
@interface MyBaseClass : NSObject
-(void)printName;
+(NSString*)printableName;
@end

@implementation MyBaseClass

-(void)printName
{
    [[self class] printableName];
}

+(NSString*)printableName {
    return @"hello";
}

@end
```

Comment: It only compiles because `NSClass#name` exists. I should've picked a better example name. But if I use `nameForID:` (which is what I'm using in my actual code), I get a 'cannot resolve' error.

Comment: Just updated the code to use `printableName` instead of `name`.

Comment: And to inherit from `NSObject`, as it does in the original code. Sorry for the sloppy transcription.

Comment: That error you're getting sounds like you're trying to invoke printableName on a pointer to NSObject, not a pointer to MyBaseClass.

Comment: Still get: Method 'printableName' is defined in class 'MyBaseClass' and is not visible at line 12

Comment: Line 12 refers to `[[self class] printableName]`

Comment: @Bill: Did you directly copy and paste Graham's code into a file and it failed the same way? Because it works for other people. That's why he said he didn't think you were using the same code.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `[object_getClass(this) printableName]`?

(But you realize, of course, that you could also just create a version of

```
-(NSString*)printableName2 {
    return [MyBaseClass printableName]; 
}
```

in each of your classes and call `[self printableName2]`?)

Answer (score 0):

From what you are describing, it should work. As you didn't offer your implementation, we won't be able to tell, what is wrong.

Based on this question, I wrote an example code for [polymorphism in Objective-C](https://github.com/vikingosegundo/my-programming-examples/blob/master/polly/polly/main.m).
It contains inheritance-based polymorphism, but also polymorphism based on formal and informal protocols. May you want check your code against it.

here an excerpt:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

/*
 * 1.: Polymorphism via subclassing 
 */
@interface MyBaseClass : NSObject
-(void)printName;
+(NSString*)printableName;
@end

@implementation MyBaseClass

+(NSString *)printableName
{
    return NSStringFromClass(self);
}

-(void)printName
{
    NSLog(@"%@", [[self class] printableName]);
}

@end


@interface MySubBaseClass : MyBaseClass
@end

@implementation MySubBaseClass
@end

//...

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    /*
     * 1.: Polymorphism via subclassing. As seen in any Class-aware OO-language
     */
    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    MyBaseClass *myBaseObject = [[MyBaseClass alloc] init];
    [myBaseObject printName];
    [myBaseObject release];

    MySubBaseClass *mySubBaseObject = [[MySubBaseClass alloc] init];
    [mySubBaseObject printName];
    [mySubBaseObject release];

    //...

    [pool drain];
    return 0;
}
```